# Regex is working on Regex101 but not inside Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, text

I have this Text file:

```
[Tabs]
MAILBOXSEND=1
MAILBOX=8
USERS=6
DOCUMENTS_Q=9
MED_WEBSERVCALLS_LOA=3
FCLMNA=1
INCZOOMFORM=1
USERSB=1
USERSB_ONE=1
DATAPRIV=1
MED_WEBSERVCALLS=2
TINVOICES=1
PORDERS=9
PORDERSTOTAL=1
LOGPART=1
LOGCOUNTERS=1
PARTMSG=1
[External Mail]
Send=Y
Hostname=Server
Domain=Domain
Myemail=My@email.com
MyName=My Test
Port=25
SSL=0
[Search]
SUPPLIERS=5,1
StartButton=1
Ignore Case=0
PART=6,1
```

I'm Trying to capture all the text between `[External Mail]` to the Next `[]` Brackets Group,

I have this Regex which do the job and tested in Regex101, after all the testing's I found it's not working inside powershell:

```
$Text = Get-Content c:\text.txt
$Text -match '(?s)(?<=\[External Mail\]).*?(?=\[.*?\])'
or:
$Text | Select-String '(?s)(?<=\[External Mail\]).*?(?=\[.*?\])'
```

Nothing Return

Do you have any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you protected your `\ `?

Comment: I would not use regex for this. Either convert to an object yourself or use something along the lines of [Get-INIContent](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file.aspx). Thank you for adding your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to get a multiline regex match you need to be working against a single multiline string. That is the difference between your two cases of regex101 and PowerShell. `Get-Content` will be returning a string *array*. Your regex was not matching anything as it was only doing the test on single lines within the file.

PowerShell 2.0

```
$Text = Get-Content c:\text.txt | Out-String
```

PowerShell 3.0 of higher

```
$Text = Get-Content c:\text.txt -Raw
```

As I said in my comments you don't really need regex, in this way, for this type of string extraction. [There are scripts that already exist to parse INI content](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file.aspx). If you intend to be replacing content you would have to find the partner cmdlet `Out-INIContent` assuming it exists but I am sure someone made it. [vonPryz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35061868/3829407) contains more information on the cmdlet

Comment: You just ninja-added the .Ini parser link I was so happy to show off with :-P

Comment: @vonPryz Yeah ... I had it in my earlier comment but though it would be better as part of an answer.

Comment: @JustCurious I told you how in my answer? I explained how to fix your problem. I have not tested your regex though..... is it still not working

Comment: @JustCurious You didn't make that clear... all you said was _anyway to do it with regex_.  I will check your regex against the file myself.

Comment: @JustCurious Works fine for me `$Text = Get-Content "c:\temp\text.txt" -Raw; $Text -match '(?s)(?<=\[External Mail\]).*?(?=\[.*?\])'; $Matches[0]`. Just need to do the replace now..... I only used the semicolons as code in comments sucks. That is three lines

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are parsing an .INI file. Don't try to invent the wheel again, take leverage from [existing code](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file.aspx). This solution reads the .Ini file as nested hash tables that are easy to work with.

In case of link rot, here's the function from Scripting Guys archive:

```
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
{
    $ini = @{}
    switch -regex -file $FilePath
    {
        "^\[(.+)\]" # Section
        {
            $section = $matches[1]
            $ini[$section] = @{}
            $CommentCount = 0
        }
        "^(;.*)$" # Comment
        {
            $value = $matches[1]
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
            $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        } 
        "(.+?)\s*=(.*)" # Key
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
    }
    return $ini
}

# Sample usage:
$i = Get-IniContent c:\temp\test.ini
$i["external mail"]

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Domain                         Domain
SSL                            0
Hostname                       Server
Send                           Y
MyName                         My Test
Port                           25
Myemail                        My@email.com

$i["external mail"].hostname
Server
```

Comment: any easy way to replace a complete section? or just to create a new one with all the details(foreach or something) ?